# Smalltalk initialization variables

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

In languages like Java and C++ we give parameters to constructors.

How do you do this in Pharo Smalltalk?

I want something like

```
|aColor|
aColor = Color new 'red'.
```

Or is this bad practice and should I always do

```
|aColor|
aColor = Color new.
aColor name:= red.d
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The short answer is that you can do pretty much the same in Smalltalk. From the calling code it would look like:

```
aColor := Color named: 'Red'.
```

The long answer is that in Smalltalk you don't have constructors, at least not in the sense that you have a special message named after the class. What you do in Smalltalk is defining class-side messages (i.e. messages understood by the class, not the instance[*]) where you can instantiate and configure your instances. Assuming that your `Color` class has a `name` instance variable and a setter for it, the `#named:` method would be implemented like:

```
(class) Color>>named: aName
| color |
color := self new.
color name: aName.
^color.
```

Some things to note:

- We are using the `#new` message sent to the class to create a new instance. You can think of the `#new` message as the primitive way for creating objects (hint: you can browse the implementors of the `#new` message to see how it is implemented).
- We can define as many class methods as we want to create new 'configured' instances (e.g. `Color fromHexa:`) or return pre-created ones (e.g. `Color blue`).
- You can still create an uninitialized instance by doing `Color new`. If you want to forbid that behavior then you must override the `#new` class message.

There are many good books that you can read about Smalltalk basics at [Stef's Free Online Smalltalk Books](http://stephane.ducasse.free.fr/FreeBooks.html)

[*] This is quite natural due to the orthogonal nature on Smalltalk, since everything (including classes) is an object. If you are interested check Chapter 13 of [Pharo by Example](http://pharobyexample.org/) or any other reference to classes and metaclasses in Smalltalk.

HTH

Comment: Even better is not having any setters, and a single initialization method parameterised as needed: `Color >> #initializeWithName:` in this case.

Comment: To clarify a bit, the class is an object, the instance is another object. To respect encapsulation, the class has no access to instance variables of the instance - except by kindly asking thru message send. It's pretty uniform, Smalltalk is about sending messages, even for such basic kernel tasks... As FrankShearar said, it might be better to have a single message at instance side that set all variables at once, it's up to programmers to judge.

Answer (score 3):

In Smalltalk all member fields are strictly private and to assign to them you'll have to define assigning methods.

```
Color >> name: aString
  name := aString
```

Then you could create your object like this:

```
|aColor|
aColor := (Color new)
  name: 'red';
  yourself.
```

Commonly to reduce verbosity factory method is used:

```
Color class >> withName: aName
  ^ (self new)
    name: aName;
    yourself.
```

With this you could create new objects like this:

```
|aColor|
aColor := Color withName: 'red'.
```